# Генератор кнопки на единичное скачивание

Tags: php, javascript, wordpress, платежи

Всем привет.
Нужно сделать кнопку на скачивание файла, название которого меняется после определенного количества минут после генерации имени.
Как сделать кнопку на файл я знаю. не знаю только как заставить файл на сервере менять свое имя на случайное и подставлять это имя в кнопку.
Это нужно для того, чтобы после оплаты покупки цифрового товара перебрасывало на страницу с кнопкой и чтоб эту ссылку видел лишь тот человек, который оплатил товар.
Думал с вариантами платежных агрегаторов, но там везде бешеная комиссия.
Для справки: у меня сайт на вордпресс без плагина вукомерс. Думаю можно какой-то обработчик событий повесить на кнопку или какую-то функцию на php.

Answer (score 1):

Подход неправильный. Так вы сможете продать файл только одному покупателю. А если их несколько одновременно?

Вам надо не файл переименовывать, а продавать случайным образом сгенерированные ссылки на него. Ссылка должна быть вида `/download.php?link=код_ссылки`. Ваш обработчик должен:

- инициализировать ядро WordPress
- проверить права пользователя на обладание этой ссылкой
- проверить время жизни ссылки
- в случае успешных проверок, отдать реальный файл на скачивание.

Такой функционал есть в WooCommerce, от которого вы напрасно отказались.

Comment: Дело в том, что у меня несколько страниц-лендингов. Каждая из которых продает отдельный курс обучения. На каждой странице очень много чего сказано. И я не знал как приплести сюда WooCommerce, поэтому пошел сложным путем, о чем сейчас жалею.

Comment: Понятно, что WooCommerce в этом проекте вы уже вряд ли сможете использовать. Потому я написал о том, как сделать продажу множества ссылок на один реальный файл.